# How to compare two timestamp values?

Tags: c#, sql

This is a SQL 2005 DB - so **no rowversion**. This applies to the **timestamp** datatype in SQL Server.

When I load a record I want to compare the old timestamp with the current one to see if any changes have been made.

if (old == new) always returns false yet they appear identical?

Am I missing something?

Old:
{byte[8]}
    [0]: 0
    [1]: 0
    [2]: 0
    [3]: 0
    [4]: 0
    [5]: 0
    [6]: 15
    [7]: 168

New:
{byte[8]}
    [0]: 0
    [1]: 0
    [2]: 0
    [3]: 0
    [4]: 0
    [5]: 0
    [6]: 15
    [7]: 168

Comment: Have you tried using the `TSEQUAL` function?  It works like this: `TSEQUAL(TS1, TS2)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to manually compare the bytes using a loop (or use `SequenceEqual` when you are using .NET 3.5 or higher), instead of comparing *the references*.